# Could not connect to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have created a new Springboot application. I am getting an error in POM.xml which is,

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-sample-activemq:[unknown-version]: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-samples:pom:${revision} from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PROXY and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

I have tried updating and cleaning the project. But did not work.
Tried deleting the contents in m2/repositry folder but did not work.

My Settings.xml looks like this,

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>PROXY</host>
      <port>3120</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>maven</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

and also i am trying to connect the url through telnet in cmd. but it say
Connecting To repo.maven.apache.org...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3120: Connect failed

My POM.xml Looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-activemq</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Boot ActiveMQ Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot ActiveMQ Sample</description>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am working in office environment ..could it be because of firewall issue.. please help ??

Comment: PROXY should be the URL of your http proxy

Comment: Thats what i have mentioned in settings.xml ..

Comment: But this can't be the name of your http proxy server.

Comment: ok..i am trying with the ip of my system as proxy....

Comment: and maybe you have to authenticate

Comment: Project->maven->Update Project->tick all checkboxes expect offline then try it

Comment: @DipakThoke, i have tried that too before.. but did not work

Comment: The first thing is to remove the `${revision}` part in your parent. Replace it with for example `2.0.4.RELEASE` for Spring Boot 2.X....Furthermore try first on plain command line ....not inside of Eclipse/IDEA...

Comment: @khmarbaise it was not the problem with that, its with firewall blockage which was solved my accessing the proxy settings of my system

Answer (score 0):

There is maybe a proxy issue, but first, you're getting `Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-samples:pom:${revision}` just because there is no artifact `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-samples` in Maven Central : https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.boot%20AND%20a:spring-boot-samples. You are also referring to a property (`${revision}`) not defined in your POM.

I think you have just copied the [example from GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.0.M1/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-activemq/pom.xml) where `spring-boot-samples` [is actually defined](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.0.M1/spring-boot-samples/pom.xml), but this is **an internal module**.

You should first read Spring Boot docs about bootstraping projects. Have you noticed the comment in `<parent>` section of the POM?

```
<!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
```

For issues related to the proxy, I suggest you to read more [about configuring proxies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html). You also probably need authentication.

Comment: actually you are correct that is pom.xml from githun but even i tried with my own Pom.xml...but even the result was same

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: Do you have the same error? Because I've just tested that on my machine and it works (no proxy).

Comment: yes.i do have the same error.. is it something related to firewall.. which is stoping to connect to maven repo.. ?

Comment: Read the [guide on proxies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html). Are you able to access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ without enabled proxy?

Comment: it was a proxy issue..i changed it my system proxy settings which is available at internet options -> connections -> lan settings ->...that worked!!

Comment: Glad it worked :). Don't forget to accept the answer to help other people facing similar issues.